# Google Services draining battery of Nexus 6

Tags: android

This happened three times in the last month:

My Nexus 6 battery drained in several hours. When I reboot and go to battery usage, I always found Google Services uses up to 90% of the battery. However there is no application on my Nexus 6 called "Google Services". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means the apps made by Google. In my case, I had problems with Gmail and Google Fit that were draining my phone.

Disabling Google Fit (which is useless in my case) and removing non-google accounts from gmail (hotmail, yahoo, customs) and putting them in their native app solved the problem for me.

Hope this helps ! Good luck ;)